# How can I join only one record on a has_many with criteria in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

If I have the following models how can I return all reports a user has created, but only the "highest graded" report per player?

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
end

class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :grade
  belongs_to :player
end

class Grade < ApplciationRecord
  has_many :reports
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
end
```

Example Data:

```
/Player/    -    /Author/   -    /Report Grade/
John Smith        -    David      -        5
John Smith        -    David      -        4
Thomas Li         -    David      -        5
Mike Lee          -    Sean       -        9
Mike Lee          -    Sean       -        2
Arnold Jackson    -    Sean       -        5
Cathleen Miller   -    Sean       -        7
```

Result I would like:

```
/Player/    -    /Author/   -    /Report Grade/
John Smith        -    David      -        5
Thomas Li         -    David      -        5
Mike Lee          -    Sean       -        9
Arnold Jackson    -    Sean       -        5
Cathleen Miller   -    Sean       -        7
```

Currently I'm using the following:

```
Report.joins(:player).where(type: %w(spring fall))
```

I'm unsure how to filter out the "lower graded" records.  If I need to include more information please let me know.

Comment: Do you really need a separate table for `Grade`? It would a lot simpler if you just used an integer on `reports`.

Comment: @max, yes the grade values are more complex than shown here.  I just simplified it for the illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Postgres you can use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :grade
  belongs_to :author

  def self.highest_graded
    Report.select(%q{
      DISTINCT ON(reports.player_id, reports.author_id)
      grades.grade AS max_grade,
      players.name AS player_name,
      authors.name AS author_name,
      reports.*
    }).joins(:player, :grade, :author)
      .order('reports.player_id, reports.author_id, grades.grade DESC')
  end
end
```

---

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% Report.highest_grade.each do |report| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= report.id %></td>
      <td><%= report.player_name %></td>
      <td><%= report.author_name %></td>
      <td><%= report.max_grade %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
id  Player          Author  Grade
1   John Smith      David   5
3   Thomas Li       David   5
4   Mike Lee        Sean    9
6   Arnold Jackson  Sean    5
7   Cathleen Miller Sean    7
```